# Efficient approach to nested navigation structure in Angular

Tags: angular, performance, angular-ng-if

Let's assume I have the following tree structure:

```
    Item1            Item2            Item3            Item4             Itemn  
  /   |   \        /   |   \        /   |   \        /   |   \         /   |   \
 /    |    \      /    |    \      /    |    \      /    |    \       /    |    \
 a    b    c      d    e    f      g    h     i     j    k     l     n-2   n-1   n
```

Each node from `a,b,...,n` has values.
What's a more efficient way to structure this navigation?

My approach is he following:

Create an array `toggleStatus` that contains boolean values.
Assign a number to each tab which is respectively equal to the index of `toggleStatus`.
A method `toggle(index)` will toggle the value of `toggleStatus` at index `index`.

Please have a look at my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmrdhj) for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add all the data directly into your HTML. You can just create an array of objects which will make it perfect for a nested `ngFor` case.

Your data will look something like this

```js
menus: any[] = [{
    item: 'Item 1', submenus: [
        { item: 'a', info: 'Info of a' },
        { item: 'b', info: 'Info of b' },
        { item: 'c', info: 'Info of c' }
    ]
}, {
    item: 'Item 2', submenus: [
        { item: 'd', info: 'Info of d' },
        { item: 'e', info: 'Info of e' },
        { item: 'f', info: 'Info of f' }
    ]
}, {
    item: 'Item 3', submenus: [
        { item: 'g', info: 'Info of g' },
        { item: 'h', info: 'Info of h' },
        { item: 'i', info: 'Info of i' }
    ]
}, {
    item: 'Item 4', submenus: [
        { item: 'j', info: 'Info of j' },
        { item: 'k', info: 'Info of k' },
        { item: 'l', info: 'Info of l' }
    ]
}];
```

Then in your HTML, we will loop over the `menus` using `ngFor`

```html
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div (click)="toggleMenu(i)" class="text-white cursor-pointer text-center">
        <div class="py-4 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-400">
            {{menu.item}}
        </div>
        <div class="container" *ngIf="showSubmenu[i]">
            <!-- Submenus -->
            <ng-container *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenus; let j = index">
                <div (click)="toggleSubmenu($event, submenu.item)" class="py-3 w-1/3 inline-block"
                    [ngClass]="{'bg-blue-200': j === 0, 'bg-blue-300': j === 1, 'bg-blue-400': j === 2}">
                    {{submenu.item}}
                </div>
            </ng-container>
            <!-- Information -->
            <div *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenus; let j = index">
                <div *ngIf="showInfo[submenu.item]" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="py-3 bg-green-400">
                    {{submenu.info}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your component, we shall define the flags and the `toggle` functions. I have used an array for flags. We will dynamically insert the toggle flag into this array based on the index. [`$event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) is used to prevent the `click` event from bubbling up into the parent element's `click` event. Here's how the component will look

```js
showSubmenu: any[] = [];
showInfo: any[] = [];

toggleMenu(index: number) {
    this.showSubmenu[index] = !this.showSubmenu[index];
}

toggleSubmenu(event: MouseEvent, item: string) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.showInfo[item] = !this.showInfo[item];
}
```

> Note: The `item` passed to the`toggleSubmenu` should be a unique value. If you have an `id`, it would be preferred to use that here instead of `item`.

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-ngfor-menu) of the same.

Comment: Beautiful! How would I proceed if I also wanted to show not only plain text, but html code?

Comment: Just use `[innerHTML]` instead to display the values. Check out my StackBlitz, I updated the Info part to show the data using `innerHTML` and I modified the first item in `menus` to have HTML content in the submenu's info.

Answer (score 1):

here I have some sample code through an array
in your ts

```
 toggleArray = [{ name:'Item 1',subItems: [{name:'a',msg:'this is a',isExpand:false},{name:'b',msg:'this is b',isExpand:false},{name:'c',msg:'this is c',isExpand:false}] ,isExpand : false},{ name:'Item 2',subItems: [{name:'d',msg:'this is d',isExpand:false},{name:'e',msg:'this is e',isExpand:false},{name:'f',msg:'this is f',isExpand:false}] ,isExpand : false}]
  toggleItem(item) {
    item.isExpand = item.isExpand ? false:true;
    item.subItems.forEach((item) => {
      item.isExpand = false;
    })
  }
  toggleSubItem(subitem) {
    subitem.isExpand = subitem.isExpand ? false:true;
  }
```

in your HTML. I just put logic please fix CSS whatever you needed.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of toggleArray" (click)="toggleItem(item)" class="p-4 bg-blue-600 text-white hover:bg-blue-400 cursor-pointer text-center">
    {{item.name}}
     <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div *ngIf="item.isExpand" class="flex flex-row justify-between">
      <div *ngFor="let subitem of item.subItems" (click)="toggleSubItem(subitem)" class="py-3 w-1/3 text-center bg-blue-200">
        {{subitem.name}}
        <div class="container mx-auto">
          <div *ngIf="subitem.isExpand" class="flex flex-row justify-between">
            <div  (click)="toggleSubItem(subitem)" class="py-3 w-1/3 text-center bg-blue-200">
              {{subitem.msg}}
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```